# How to remove scratches from 5th generation iPod?

Tags: ipod, macos

I own a [5th generation iPod](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1353#ipodfifth) with a lot of scratches on its acrylic-like surface and display that I'd like to be removed (please note it's not a touch-screen iPod). What should I buy (preferentially on eBay) and how should I wipe all those scratches away to keep my iPod as polished as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found on this site [Repair iPod Scratches yourself Cheaply](http://www.detwiler.us/ipodpolish.html) that you can use something called Brasso to clean the back of it. It has a mild abrasive in oil. it will cost you about 5 dollars. Then to clean the face, either a microfiber cloth or a t-shirt.

EDIT:
You could try [Ice Creme](http://www.radtech.us/Products/Icecreme.aspx) its designed for iPods and Macs (or so it says).

Answer (score 1):

Using a CD scratch repair kit worked for me. One cloth had a mild solvent which softened the area and a buffing cloth to help remove surface scratches.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard screen klean is a great touch screen cleaner. Also, a good rule for touch devices is not to use anything alcohol based!

Answer (score 0):

I have had success using the compounds from TDI-LLC in removing scratches from my 5th Gen. iPod as well as my HTC Evo 4G device.  As far as "creative" scratch removal methods, they have received mixed reviews and usually contain a warning in trying those methods.  I decided to go with a solution that seemed more tried and true and have been pleased with the results on more than one occasion.  Here is their link...

[TDI-LLC Resurfacing Compounds](http://www.tdillctechnology.com/store/accessories/resurfacing-compound.html)